# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Net.CookieContainer'

Tags: c#

I simply want to set a cookie in my webrequest but can't do it because of the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Net.CookieContainer'".

If the code below doesn't work - how do you achive this?

```
    public static string GET(string url, string cookieValue, string cookieName)
    {
        string response = "";
        Uri target = new Uri(url);
        var host = target.Host;
        Cookie c = new Cookie(cookieValue, cookieName) { Domain = host };
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer().Add(c);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        WebResponse response1 = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response1.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        response = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        response1.Close();
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: don't use fluent syntax in the `new CookieContainer().Add(c)`. What you are doing there is simply create the new cookiecontainer and return the void of the Add, split this text to 2 lines (first create, then add)

Comment: Before asking on StackOverflow - debug your app to see which line of code produced exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression tries to "chain" instance creation `new` and a call to `Add`. C# allows that, but the type of the result of that expression is  `Add`'s return type, i.e. `void`, which cannot be assigned to anything.

You need to separate this line

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer().Add(c);
```

into two:

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
cookieContainer.Add(c);
```

or use the `{`-`}` syntax for invoking `Add`:

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer {
    c
};
```

Comment: @Icepickle: because it answers the question.

Comment: @Icepickle because this is an answer :p

Comment: Well, wasn't that easy. Thanks! :)

Comment: I thought we didn't help to debug code :D

Comment: @Icepickle You are right, we don't. This code didn't even compile, though, so OP couldn't use the debugger yet. The pattern of calling `Add` "inline" with the constructor could be a "false cognate" from other APIs or even other languages, so it's not a case of "please find my missing semicolon" either. Overall, I think this is an OK question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: thanks, i love the tech specs in pointing out that i said debug code (while it's an obvious syntax failure). The extra info you put after my first comment, helps me more in accepting the answer :D However, as for the question, i still think the OP took the easy way out, didn't even bother to find out why for him/herself...

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, in a way I did. I did however seriously try to figure it out but a combination of lack of skills and Friday afternoon made it difficult. So  when this answer actually helped me move forward it eliminated a small - but important for me - amount of frustration in the world :) I am grateful.

Comment: @Niko, yes, thats why i upvoted the answer and downvoted the question